# Is there a way to pass a String array containing dates from server side to client?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, pug

I am trying to pass a String array from server side to client using Nodejs and Pug, but continuously get errors like "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'" or "SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal"

The server is running v10.15.0 with PUG v2.0.3. I have tried encapsulating each element of the array in quotes. Tried a few different approaches with JSON, but keep getting the same errors. With the code below when I print the array in the console I get (only 4 elements, rest removed here for shortness):
    [ '"2017-04-01T02:43:39.000Z"',
    '"2017-04-01T06:37:05.000Z"',
    '"2017-04-01T10:30:22.000Z"',
    '"2017-04-01T14:23:41.000Z"',...]
I am literally lost at this time, can you please help?

```
//Server side
client.execute(query,[], function(err, result){
        if(err){
            res.status(404).send({msg: err});
        } else {
            for (i in result.rows){
                currentDate = new Date(result.rows[i].event_time);
                dates.push('"'+ currentDate.toJSON()+'"');
                //dates.push(currentDate.toJSON());

            }
            if (result.rows[0] != null) {
                res.render(page, {
                    datesA: dates,
                    //datesA: JSON.stringify(dates),
                });
            else {
                res.status(404).send({msg: err});
            }
        }
    });
//PUG
var dates =JSON.parse(#{datesA});
//var dates = JSON.parse(#{datesA});
//var dates = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(#{datesA});
//var dates = #{datesA};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in pug file (in script section):

```
var dates = !{JSON.stringify(datesA)};
```